# How to test azure worker role in the local machine?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have azure worker role: **ImportDataWorker** but when I set it up as startup project it doesn't allow me to run the project:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to set the Cloud Service project as Startup Project. And then add this worker class library as Worker Role to the Cloud Service Project.

Comment: yeah, but I am thinking how to test it with unit tests? Should I reference the worker role into test project then?

Comment: Yep. For testing you shall reference the Worker Role project. Well the way I do is to abstract my core workers into a separate class library. Then I reference this class library into both Worker Role and Test projects.